# Table cell border not visible in Thunderbird

Tags: html, thunderbird

I can't find any answer online, and was hopping someone could help me.

OK

My question is very simple im trying to acheive the following.

In browser it is working perfectly. but in thunder bird there is no line separating them.
[image]

Im using `<table>` since i could not v-align price to the lowest one in other way.

Any how this is my code.

```
<style>
    .verticalLineSimilar
    {
        border-right:1px grey solid;
        width: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .similarTitle
    {
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 160px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .similarImage
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .similarImage img
    {
        max-height:100px;
        max-width:100px;
    }
    .simiarPrice
    {
        color:red;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
    }

</style>
<div id="RecommendationForYou" style="text-align: center;">
    <table style="display: inline-block;">
        <tr>
            <td class="similarTitle">{!=>SimilarTitle1<=!}</td>
            <td class="verticalLineSimilar" rowspan="3"></td>
            <td class="similarTitle">{!=>SimilarTitle2<=!}</td>
            <td class="verticalLineSimilar" rowspan="3"></td>
            <td class="similarTitle">{!=>SimilarTitle3<=!}</td>
            <td class="verticalLineSimilar" rowspan="3"></td>
            <td class="similarTitle">{!=>SimilarTitle4<=!}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="similarImage"><img src="{!=>SimilarImage1<=!}"></td>
            <td class="similarImage"><img src="{!=>SimilarImage2<=!}"></td>
            <td class="similarImage"><img src="{!=>SimilarImage3<=!}"></td>
            <td class="similarImage"><img src="{!=>SimilarImage4<=!}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="simiarPrice">$ {!=>SimilarPrice1<=!}</td>
            <td class="simiarPrice">$ {!=>SimilarPrice2<=!}</td>
            <td class="simiarPrice">$ {!=>SimilarPrice3<=!}</td>
            <td class="simiarPrice">$ {!=>SimilarPrice4<=!}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I also tried the following

```
.verticalLineSimilar
    {
        width: 1px;
        background-color: grey;
    }
```

But the td wont go lower than 3px witch look very unprofessional 
[image]

Is there something im doing wrong or something that i should do that could let me actually show those line in thunderbird.

Thanks for any help I could get!

Answer (score 1):

For some weird reason thunder bird won't allow border on td element.

So what I did is an

```
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
border-right:1px grey solid;
```

on a div inside of the td element that was suposed to do the border.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem trivial, but have your tried using rgb (128,128,128) or hex color (#808080)?